# Rails ActionMailer is injecting carriage returns before newlines in attachments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, actionmailer

I have am using ActionMailer to send a CSV that I am generating. The CSV content is as follows:

```
download_file = "Requestor Name,Job Name,Number of workers needed,Number of workers ranked,Venue,Street Address,City,State,Zip code,List of required badges,List of accepted Worker's name & email ,Job Request state,Flexible Start Time,Job Request Start Time,Job Request Max Start Time,List of Selected Date,Job Request duration,Multi-day Job,Multi-day Job ID,Number of unpaid breaks,Break minutes\nJohn Doe,Request name 1,1,,,575 Market street,San Francisco,CA,94105,\"\",\"\",posted,No,\"Jun 3 2019, 4:03pm\",,\"\",,No,,,\nJohn Doe,Request name 1,1,,,575 Market street,San Francisco,CA,94105,\"\",\"\",posted,No,\"Jun 3 2019, 4:03pm\",,\"\",,No,,,\nJohn Doe,Request name 1,1,,,575 Market street,San Francisco,CA,94105,\"\",\"\",posted,No,\"Jun 3 2019, 4:03pm\",,\"\",,No,,,\n"
```

I then assign it to become an attachment:

```
attachments["#{file_name}_#{export_time}.csv"] = download_file
```

I then test the content. The test fails. I see that the attachment looks like this:

```
"Requestor Name,Job Name,Number of workers needed,Number of workers ranked,Venue,Street Address,City,State,Zip code,List of required badges,List of accepted Worker's name & email ,Job Request state,Flexible Start Time,Job Request Start Time,Job Request Max Start Time,List of Selected Date,Job Request duration,Multi-day Job,Multi-day Job ID,Number of unpaid breaks,Break minutes\r\nJohn Doe,Request name 1,1,,,575 Market street,San Francisco,CA,94105,\"\",\"\",posted,No,\"Jun 3 2019, 4:03pm\",,\"\",,No,,,\r\nJohn Doe,Request name 1,1,,,575 Market street,San Francisco,CA,94105,\"\",\"\",posted,No,\"Jun 3 2019, 4:03pm\",,\"\",,No,,,\r\nJohn Doe,Request name 1,1,,,575 Market street,San Francisco,CA,94105,\"\",\"\",posted,No,\"Jun 3 2019, 4:03pm\",,\"\",,No,,,\r\n"
```

Notice that now all the `\n` code has been replaced with `\r\n` code. This occurred when upgrading from Rails 4.1 to 4.2. What is going on here?

Also, I cannot edit the attachment. The body of the attachment has a `raw_source` attribute but neither the body nor the raw_source are editable, so I cannot gsub it out. What can I do here to remove the new `\r`?

Comment: Not sure, if I missunderstood, but why should `gsub` not be an option. You don't have to edit the file. You load the data into a variable, do the gsub there then assign it as attachment. Why should that not work?

Comment: Because the attachment has a body, with a raw_source, that is uneditable. I tried that.